# glsl using only vertex shader object loses color/texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I need only a vertex shader functionality, but without fragment shader my object is just black. How do I write a fragment shader, if i need one, so the object won't lose it's color? The closest i get to it is the following set:

In vertex shader:

```
// some functionality regarding changing objects position
gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
gl_FrontSecondaryColor = gl_SecondaryColor;
gl_BackColor = gl_Color;
gl_BackSecondaryColor = gl_SecondaryColor;
```

And not loading fragment shader at all. That way object is colored but without texture. How do I keep the object's coloring/texturing as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest fragment shader you could write to just use the color you assign in the vertex shader is:

```
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
}
```

To get texturing you would need to change your vertex shader to pass along the texture coordinates by adding the following line:

```
gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
```

Your fragment shader would then be:

```
uniform sampler2D tex_sampler;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex_sampler,gl_TexCoord[0].st);
}
```

This will apply the texture to your object. I'm not sure what your original setup was like but if you want to do lighting then you will need to find out what type of lighting was originally used and implement that in the shaders as well.

Comment: That, with vertex shader unchanged just makes the object white. Should I change the vertex shader?

Comment: How are you setting the color in your application? Using gl_Color only works if you are setting the color in the application using the glColor* functions.

Comment: Object has texture, i just load the object from .flt file. I am using OpenSceneGraph, an API over openGL. So i dont work with openGL directly

Comment: That is probably why you are seeing the object as white then. If the object is meant to be drawn with a texture then generally the base color would be set to white for appropriate blending with the texture. What color were you expecting it to be and is there anywhere that you explicitly set a color?

Comment: I just want the object to look as it looked without any shaders, with texture and so on. I just need vertex shader to change it's position but i found that object turns black. So i figure i have to explicitly tell shaders to keep the color/texture on, right?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the necessary code for texturing.